# Check if a file is opened by other process without opening it in C (Linux environment)

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way to check if file is opened, whether in read mode or write mode, by some other process in another terminal, without trying to open it?

My C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    FILE *demo;
    int result;

    if (getenv("FIRST_TIME")) {
        demo = fopen("distributed.txt", "r+");
        sleep(15);
        fclose(demo);
    } else {
        demo = fopen("distributed.txt", "r+");
        printf("demo is %p \n", demo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In first terminal `FIRST_TIME` env var is set, and opened the file there. In second terminal, there is no such env var set, so it should execute the `else` part. In the `else` part I want `demo` to have `NULL` till same file is opened by first terminal, and provide me with a value when file is closed in first terminal.

Better I don't want to try opening file till that file is closed by first terminal.

Comment: Nothing very simple.  I'm not sure there's a way of finding out by opening it, either.

Comment: There's ways to find out what processes have a file open - look into the source of `lsof` for how it's done on Linux.

Comment: Or if you want to know what opens it *after* your program starts up, inotify.

Comment: This is a typical XY problem :)

Comment: @GourishSingla: don't you mean to open the file in `"w+"` mode the first time?

Comment: Conditions are same for any combination of read or write. second process can't access the file until first one closes it, whichever operation it may be performing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple nor reliable way to achieve what you want because you cannot avoid race conditions without a proper lock on the file. Whether a method returns true or false for the test *is the file xxx open by another process*, the situation may change before your process acts on this information.

You can open the file for exclusive access with the `open` system call using the `O_EXLOCK` flag. In case of success, you can then use `fdopen()` to associate the file handle with a standard stream. Yet this does not seem to address your goal.

For your inter process communication problem, you should investigate [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).